# plotting a function in MATLAB

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, 3d

I have an assignment i'm working on and I need to plot the following:

$$f(x,y)= \cos(3x)+2\sin(y+4x)$$

I always define $x$ as in the range and assign $y$ to be the function. but since it's a function of two variables I have no idea what to assign $y$ to? please help

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to define $y$ as a function of $x$ which is not at all the point here. What is asked to you is to represent not a curve but a surface with "height" $z$ at the vertical position of point $(x,y)$ computed by the given formula. Here is a Matlab program for that :

> ```
> clear all;close all ; %as always
> [X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.05:3*pi); % (explanation below) 
> Z = cos(3*X)+2*sin(Y+4*X);
> s = surf(X,Y,Z); 
> view([-5,45]); % angles of view
> set(s,'edgecolor','none'); % elimination of hideous separation lines
> ```

If you want a contour map (level lines), just replace "surf" by "contour", producing "standard" contour lines.
 [image]

*Fig. 1 : Nice "silky" effect, isn't it ?*

---

Sometimes, "meshgrid" is misunderstood.

First of all, in the above program, we could have used it like this :

[X,Y]=meshgrid(0:0.05:4*pi,0:0.05:2*pi), yielding a rectangular space of representation, instead of a square one.

Now for the understanding of what $X$ and $Y$ really are, let us take a very simple example :

Consider instruction : [X,Y]=meshgrid([3,4],[7,8,9]) which gives :

$$X=\begin{matrix} 3  &   4 \\ 
     3  &   4\\   
     3  &   4  \end{matrix} , \ \ \  Y=\begin{matrix}   7   &  7\\
     8   &  8\\
       9  &   9\end{matrix}$$

When the two above arrays are "grouped", you get :

$$\begin{matrix} (3,7)  &   (4,7) \\ 
     (3,8)  &   (4,8)\\   
     (3,9)  &   (4,9)   \end{matrix} $$

which is plainly the cartesian product $[3,4] \times [7,8,9]$.

That's what $X$ and $Y$ really are.

Comment: oh!!!! thank you very much. so I don't use the plot function? because theres an another question of my assignment that asks me to draw a function in mesh, surf and contour3. so I figured I wouldn't use any of them in the first question.

Comment: No, "plot" is for curves in the plane, "plot3' is for curves in 3D space. If you want a contour map (= level lines) example, I can insert it in my example.

Comment: can I use the same method you just did (creating two square arrays of values) to draw a function using different plotting functions? (mesh, surf,..) thank you so much

Comment: For understanding how meshgrid works, see the explanation I just wrote.

Comment: you don't know how much you've helped me. thank you so much. I finished the first task which was plotting 5 functions!! I have to write a function for newton's algorithm now

Comment: Pleasure. Thanks for your thanks, it is not so usual. Greet Newton for me, old acquaintance...